# Azure Synapse Pipeline Notebook Return Error

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse, spark-notebook

I want to create pipeline on Azure Synapse and one of the flow is using notebook to read, validate and then continue the pipeline or stop the pipeline

```
if(validation=True): #success on validation
   return df #continue the pipeline
if(validation=False): #failed on validation
   return error #stop the pipeline
```

I already research in stackoverflow and google but I can't find the specific way. I already tried break and mssparkutils.notebook.exit but it doesn't worked

Answer (score 1):

Already solve. you can do this

```
if validations==True:
   print(df)
else:
   raise TypeError('Validation failed')
```